# Angular ng-select validate selection

Tags: angular, angular-ngselect

I have an ng-select selection box and a button Apply, that confirms the selection. There is a **Person** object, that has **id** and **name**, and all the **names** are displayed in the dropdown for the user to choose.

The idea is that the user selects a name (while he can type to filter the results) and then confirms, sending the chosen option to the server and saving it to the database.

The problem is that instead of selecting an option from the filtered results, the user can also type an invalid input (a non-existing name) and confirm. I dont want to let that happen.

I would like to disable the Apply button if the input is not valid (it means it has not been selected from the results AND it does not match any of the results, in case that user only typed the name correctly and hasnt clicked on it in the dropdown). How can I do that?

Here is my code:

```
<ng-select [items]="allPersons" [(ngModel)]="currentPersonId" 
    bindLabel="name" bindValue="id"
    (change)="storeNewPersonName($event)">
</ng-select>
<button (click)="updatePerson()">
    <strong>Apply</strong>
</button>
```

the storeNewPersonName($event) function is called every time the user **selects a name from the dropdown**. It stores the name in a variable. Then in updatePerson() this variable is converted into a Person object and sent to server.

**tl;dr**:

So basically I need to take the current input as the user types, compare it to all existing Person names (which I store in an array), and disabling the confirm button if the input doesn't match or is empty, enabling it otherwise.

Any ideas? Thank you for help.